# from arrays to series in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I  parse some arrays to series in JavaScript?

For example :

From this :

```
var labels=[4, 5, 6];
var ff=[111, 222, 555];
var gg=[444, 777, 986];
```

To this :

```
series :[{
label : 4,
data : [{x : 111,
y : 444}]
},{
label : 5,
data : [{x : 222,
y : 777}]
},{
label : 6,
data : [{x : 555,
y : 986}]
}]
```

I've tried this :

```
var series = [];
    var data=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {

        var dataobj={
                'x' : ff[i],
                'y' : gg[i]};
        data.push(dataobj);
        var obj = {
            'label' : labels[i],
            'data': data    
        };
        series.push(obj);

    }
```

Comment: What *specifically* are you having problems with? Adding values to an array? Creating objects from the data? There is nothing here you wouldn't learn in a JS tutorial. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_object

Comment: If none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the length of all the 3 arrays is same

```
var series = [];

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var obj = {
        'label' : labels[i],
        'x' : ff[i],
        'y' : gg[i]
    };
    series.push(obj);

}
```

For your reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/DEmNvRxNMPL5qeaTwK3S?p=preview

**EDIT w.r.t. Updated Question**

```
var series = [];

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var obj = {
        'label' : labels[i],
         'data' : [{
          'x' : ff[i],
          'y' : gg[i]
         }]
      };
    series.push(obj);

}
```

For your reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/dBI9GgPOttVv6TKzazlp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they will always be the same `length`

```js
var labels = [4, 5, 6];
var ff = [111, 222, 555];
var gg = [444, 777, 986];

var series = [];

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  var obj = {
    'label': labels[i],
    'x': ff[i],
    'y': gg[i]
  };
  series.push(obj);
}

console.log(series);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like this :

```
var labels=[4, 5, 6];
var ff=[111, 222, 555];
var gg=[444, 777, 986];

function parse(labels,ff,gg,length){
var out=[],obj;  
for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
    obj={};
    obj['label']=labels[i];
    obj['x']=ff[i];
    obj['y']=gg[i];
    out.push(obj);

}
return out;
}
parse(labels,ff,gg,3);
```

Comment: What good is a function that relies on global variables? If you want to make a reusable function then it needs parameters.